# How could I use join query to find the intersection

Tags: mysql

I want to find the users who haven't make any order

My idea is that, `Get all user ids and substract the  unique ids in orders table`

How could I convert it in MySQL query syntax.

```
mysql> select * from users;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from orders;
+------+---------+--------+
| id   | user_id | amount |
+------+---------+--------+
|    1 |       1 |  10.00 |
|    1 |       2 |   5.00 |
+------+---------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to make make a left join between users (left table) and orders table.

Then from this joined table you need to filter those records which don't have any order. So in this case orders.id would be NULL.

```
SELECT 
users.id
FROM users
LEFT JOIN orders
ON users.id = orders.user_id
WHERE orders.id IS NULL
```

**Visual Understanding:**

[image]

SQL Joins explained better [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from users where id not in (select user_id from orders)
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of how this code solves the question. This will help OP learn from your answer as well as help future searchers.